# Where in task manager can I find information about GDI objects or handles per process

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2012, task-manager

On Windows7 or Windows Server 2008 i could view the total number of GDI objects or handles opened by a process in task manager. I could do this by selecting optional columns in menu: `task manager menu -> view -> select columns...`
I don't see these options in newer versions of Windows (Windows8 or Windows Server 2012). Were they deliberately removed or just relocated to another place? How do i get this information on new systems?

Comment: Definitely there on Windows 10. Right click the column titles to select columns.

Comment: @DavidMarshall I didn't know you can select them like that, thank you. I expected it to be available in the menu as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is written for Windows 10, but should work on 8 and 2012 too.

In order to select them, you need to the following:

First, if you aren't already using the more detailed view, press <kbd>More details</kbd> in the bottom left corner.

Then at the top, go to the `Details` tab.

From here, right-click the column header and choose Select columns.

A big list with columns are available to choose from.